# mysql Subquery error Unknown column 'tv.last_time' in 'where clause'

Tags: mysql, subquery

When I use mysql to do subqueries, I get Unknown column 'tv.last_time' in 'where clause', what should I do? I want to use external conditions to filter out non-conforming records when doing subqueries

```
SELECT
    info_topic.*, b.newMessage
FROM
    info_topic
LEFT JOIN `info_topic_visit` AS tv ON tv.topic_id = info_topic.id
AND tv.user_id = 225
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT
        p.topic_id,
        count(*) AS newMessage
    FROM
        info_post p
    WHERE
        p.create_time > tv.last_time
    GROUP BY
        p.topic_id
) AS b ON b.topic_id = info_topic.id
ORDER BY b.newMessage DESC
```

> database schema:

```
CREATE TABLE `info_topic` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT '' COMMENT 'topic name',
  `summary` varchar(500) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT '' COMMENT 'summary`',
  `create_time` datetime DEFAULT NULL COMMENT '',
  `sort` int(11) DEFAULT '0' COMMENT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
);

CREATE TABLE `info_topic_visit` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `topic_id` int(11) DEFAULT '0' COMMENT '',
  `user_id` int(11) DEFAULT '0' COMMENT '',
  `last_time` datetime DEFAULT NULL COMMENT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);
```

Comment: can you share the database schema for the tables used in your query, with some sample data. Also, what is your desired output data.

Comment: Ok, I will simplify it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your subquery is that the `tv` alias has no meaning there, so you can't reference anything from the table to which that alias corresponds.  One approach would be to instead convert your subquery into a correlated subquery in the select clause:

```
SELECT
    i.*,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM info_post p
     WHERE p.create_time > tv.last_time AND p.topic_id = i.id) AS newMessage
FROM info_topic i
LEFT JOIN info_topic_visit AS tv
    ON tv.topic_id = info_topic.id AND tv.user_id = 225
LEFT JOIN info_topic_member tm
    ON i.id = tm.topic_id AND
       tm.del_flag = 0    AND
       tm.apply_status = i.open_type AND
       tm.user_id = 225
WHERE
    i.del_flag = 0 AND
    i.id > 0       AND
    tm.id IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY
    newMessage DESC;
```

There might also be a way to restructure your query so that you don't need to use correlated subqueries, which are inefficient.

Comment: You might want to wait a bit to see if someone can do better.  For now, you may use this.